# How to switch language for WinJS.Resources.processAll?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, localization, winjs

When using WinJS.Resources.processAll WinJS is using the system language, which is fine. And the example at this MSDN site shows, how to change the language/context to change single strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465248.aspx#loading_strings_for_a_specific_language_or_context.

But how is it possible, to change the language for as long as WinJS.Resources.processAll would take to change a whole bunch of strings?

```
// (?) switch language just for the next call (?)
WinJS.Resources.processAll(target).next(function () {
    // (?) switch language back (?)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcecontext should get you started.

Comment: that definitly looks interesting. I try something, come back to you, if/how it works. Thanks so far!

Comment: so, I am going to overwrite WinJS.Resources.processAll(target, context) to accept a context parameter to change language for just that one call.